# MVC core routing not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core, single-page-application

So it's my first time setting up an netcore MVC based application. I've used MVC 4 in the past on plain old asp.net.

So i'm having issues with my routing. My application is an single page application (spa) that is accessible from the home controller on the index action. I can access this controller method fine, and my defaults are set so that this is navigated to at route: `/`.

I also have a second controller for authentication called `AccountController`. This controller's methods take and return JSON, rather then views. I can also access the methods on this controller from my application.

The issue i'm having lies in my next controller, which is the start of my API.
As such, i've put it in a folder called `api` inside my controllers folder. However, no matter what i try, i cannot seem to get the methods on the controller accessible. I have also tried moving it out of the api folder and just having in the route of the controllers folder.

**The routing deffinition**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/{controller=Core}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I've tried adding and removing the api definition, removing the api part, and adding a template for actions aswel, all to no effect.

**The troublesome controller**

```
public class CoreController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return Json("Dev");
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `[Route(~routing here~)]` annotations to this controller and its methods with no success either.

**Folder structure**

[image: help!]

I should also mention that i've tried plenty of URL's to access this controller on:

- /api/Core/
- /Core/
- /api/Core/Get

I've been wracking my brain for the best part of a day trying to get this sorted and i know i'm missing something obvious, i just can't for the life of me work out what it is.

## Edit:

- I've added a cut-down sample of my project to github at: https://github.com/lexwebb/aspnet-test if anyone would like a complete example

## Edit 2

It appears that my example works, i'm going to add things in to see what breaks it

Comment: putting the api controller in a sub folder instead of directly in the Controllers folder could be the problem due to conventions for controller discovery, I recommend try putting it in the Controllers directory to verify that is the issue

Comment: @JoeAudette location of class has no effect. api searches for classes by type. the OP has excluded information that may be important in identifying the problem. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi What information would be more useful? I can't exactly post the whole application?

Comment: @Nkosi I've added a complete example to github if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, i had made a mistake in a totally unrelated place. I had renamed my project half way through the beginning stage of development, after i had build scripts in place. This led to the the wrong dll being referenced on the server when the code was ran, a version that had all of my routing EXCEPT the new one, of course.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, default route requires the {action} using as well.

Instead of "api" default routing, you may to use the following configuration for such type of controllers (RESTFul controller):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CoreController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return Json("Dev");
    }
}
```

I found this [Routing is ASP.NET Core](https://stormpath.com/blog/routing-in-asp-net-core) article useful in the past.

Comment: I've tried using routing annotations as stated above with no success

Comment: @LexWebb have you tried exactly the same annotation (this is not clear from your question desc)? I had added this controller code to my test proj and got expected result via `GET /api/core`

Comment: yea i have, i'm starting to think something odd is going on as logically everything should work, could be something to do with how my spa is set up, but its kinda hard to tell